# How to calculate the number of lines in a "Java Project"

Tags: java, netbeans, line-count

How can I calculate the number of lines in a "Java Project"?
I'm using Netbeans 6.9.

Comment: Not your answer, but this also might help.You can get total number of java classes by this: `find . -name *.java | wc -l`

Comment: Did you mean `cat *.java | wc -l` or `wc -l *.java`?

Comment: zengr's command will only count the number of files found and user183037's command would not be recursive in directories

Comment: so either do shopt -s globstar && wc **/*.java in project directory or do 
`for i in \`find -name "*.java"\`; do cat $i; done | wc -l`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the [NetBeans Metrics Module](http://www.ohloh.net/p/12542).

> *NetBeans Metric Module is a module for NetBeans that can measure your java source code and display the results in NetBeans.*

---

Or the [wordcount plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=1531).

> *Counts characters, words, and lines of java files*

Answer (score 2):

Sloccount is a very good application to count number of lines of code.

You can find more information here:
[Sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/)

Comment: one should add that sloccount will usually, esp. in more complex projects give a more "sensible" answer than a normal line count since it only counts non-blank, non-comment lines and only counts a given file once (even if there are multiple copies)

Comment: there is a basic C# open source line counter here: https://github.com/StEaLtHmAn/LineCounter It counts lines, blank lines and comments of a selected file type.

Answer (score 1):

I saw what I think is a brilliantly simple answer:
Right click on the project name
Use ctl-F for Find
Specify RegEx for find
Enter \n as the search pattern
And voila - number of lines and number of files searched in the project.